# hreflang tags for language folders (in URL) - only when content is translated?

Tags: hreflang, hyperlink, translation

An SEOer that has some experience with TLDs and language folders told me the following:

If you use language folders in site (like `example.com/en/`, for all English pages), I should also give `hreflang` `en` to all pages in that URL folder - **but only if these pages are created as translations.**

Is it true? Shouldn't it be given also to non-translation webpages in that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`hreflang`** may be used on *any* link. It doesn’t matter from which and to which document you link. It just conveys in which language the linked document is.¹

**`hreflang`+[`alternate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate)** may be used only on links which point to a translation for the linking document.²

---

¹ In practice I’d only specify the `hreflang` attribute if the language of the linked document is *different* from the language of the linked document. For example, it makes sense to use it if your page is in German and you link to a Stack Overflow question (= English).

² Unless the linking document’s `html` element has a `lang` attribute with the same value like the link‘s `hreflang` attribute. In that case it wouldn’t be considered a translation, understandably.